# Does Javascript Date.getHours() include daylight saving times?

Tags: javascript, date, dst

I can't find documentation confirming that `Date.getHours()` does include local daylight saving times (local = according to user pc or device).

My tests seem to indicate that it does. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. From the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) website:

> **getHours**
> Returns the hour (0-23) in the specified date according to local time.

Clearly "local time" includes DST.

And just to be sure, in the Chrome JS Console...

> new Date()
>
> Sat Aug 03 2013 22:40:23 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)
>
> new Date().getHours()
>
> 22

I live in Italy... Here it's 22:40... And we are under DST (in winter Italy is GMT+0100)

Comment: And just to confirm: I'm in EDT and it correctly gave my EDT time, rather than EST.